# Generating a wanted number by bitwise OR

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Given N integer intervals [lo_i,hi_i].

From each interval chose a number such that bitwise OR of them become given number X.(It doesn't matter if the result has more 1 bits than X; i.e. if the generated number is Y, (X&Y)==X should hold)

Comment: only one `X` for all intervals?

Comment: for each interval pick one Y, so that `X|Y == X`?  What if there's no such number `Y` in the interval?  I'm thinking `[8, 9]` and `X = 6`

Comment: Can you provide an example? Like this?  when `X == 15`, from `[13,14]` and `[1,2]`, you chose `14` and `1` so that `(14 | 1) & X == X`.

Comment: It's easy to do it by brute force, but ridiculously slow (depending now only on N, but the size of the ranges as well) - I assume you want something reasonable? I've looked at many bipartite matching and set cover problems, but I see no way to do this properly. The best I can come up with is brute force with a little pruning (eg if a certain bit occurs only in the upper half of only one of the intervals, you must select a number from the upper half of that interval).

Comment: xor already has this property `(a xor b) xor b = a `

Comment: @John so? OP said OR, not XOR, and with that property it seems like an even harder problem - every time you choose a number it could undo previous work (so there no pruning, as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this problem is NP complete, though I haven't found an NP hard problem easily reducible to this.

But for those sets that contain 2^(mostSignificantDigit) - 1, I would do as a heuristic: Firstly, try the number `1...1` (mostSignificantDigit-1 ones), secondly a number with the most significant bit and as many other bits as possible set. This heuristic is only bad in the case that you would have required a number from the set with the most significant bit set and a few different less significant bits.

With this heuristic, you can also pick amongst those sets the largest number 1....1 as a further heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

Let's generalize the problem a little. I'm going to write bitwise operators like OR and AND and SR (shift right).

> Given a natural number X, intervals [lo_1, hi_1], ..., [lo_N, hi_N] consisting of natural numbers, and a bit b in {0, 1}, determine whether there exist natural numbers y_1 in [lo_1, hi_1], ..., y_N in [lo_N, hi_N] such that, letting Y = y_1 OR ... OR y_N, it holds that (X AND Y) = X and that there exists i such that x_i <= hi_i - b.

The base case for my recursive algorithm is when lo_1 = hi_1 = lo_2 = ... = hi_n = 0. There exists a solution if and only if X = 0 and b = 0.

Inductively, prepare a subproblem by letting X' = X SR 1 and lo_i' = lo_i SR 1 and hi_i' = hi_i SR 1. Let Odd(i) be true if and only if hi_i AND 1 = 1. Let Odd+(i) be true if and only if Odd(i) and lo_i < hi_i. If X AND 1 = 0:

> If there exists i such that Odd+(i), then let b' = 0. Otherwise, let b' = b.

If X AND 1 = 1:

> If there exist distinct i and j such that Odd+(i) and Odd(j), then let b' = 0. If there exists no j such that Odd(j), then let b' = 1. Otherwise, let b' = b.

Return the answer for the subproblem.